# Easiest way for assigning constraints to a view in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, view, constraints

I use the following method to add a view as subview and adding its constraints programatically.
This is how I create the view:

```
// In class
let view: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()
```

And this is how I add it's constraints:

```
addSubview(view)

view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
```

Is there any method in which I can achieve this easier or with less lines of code. I need constraints to be created programatically and I don't recommend using another library just for this purpose.

Comment: Currently I have created a cocoapod library named 'AutoLayoutProxy' that I'm using in all my projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not fewer lines of code, but rather than `.isActive = true`, line-by-line, I find `activate` to be a little cleaner:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
    view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
    view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
    view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
])
```

---

Or, if you're doing this a lot, write your own extension:

```
extension UIView {
    func activate(leading: NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutXAxisAnchor>? = nil,
                  trailing: NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutXAxisAnchor>? = nil,
                  top: NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutYAxisAnchor>? = nil,
                  bottom: NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutYAxisAnchor>? = nil,
                  centerX: NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutXAxisAnchor>? = nil,
                  centerY: NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutYAxisAnchor>? = nil,
                  width: CGFloat? = nil,
                  height: CGFloat? = nil) {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        if let leading = leading   { leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leading).isActive = true }
        if let trailing = trailing { trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailing).isActive = true }
        if let top = top           { topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top).isActive = true }
        if let bottom = bottom     { bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom).isActive = true }
        if let centerX = centerX   { centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerX).isActive = true }
        if let centerY = centerY   { centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerY).isActive = true }
        if let width = width       { widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true }
        if let height = height     { heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true }
    }
}
```

And then you can do it with one line of code:

```
view.activate(leading: leadingAnchor, trailing: trailingAnchor, width: 100, height: 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use visual format language. In doing so you gain conciceness but lose clarity to developers who don't understand the syntax.

If you want to setup the above constraints for a view using VFL, the code would be as follows.

```
var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[view(100)]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["view":view])
constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[view(100)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["view":view])
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
```

As you can see, for such a simple set of constraints, you don't gain a lot. However, consider you have to build a complex UI with many constraints on different objects, all relating to eachother, VFL would make doing so far easier and more concise.

VFL is very much a love it or hate it kind of thing, though I would recommend doing some reading on it so you can make your informed decision. [This](https://www.raywenderlich.com/174078/auto-layout-visual-format-language-tutorial-2) RayWendelich guide is particularly useful.

Comment: `options` has a default value of `[]`, so you can leave out `options: []` from the above calls

Comment: I have used visual constraints in the past. But these don't keep these constraints when the rotates. So, I stopped using these.

Comment: @BibinJacob - There must be something else wrong in your attempts in the past because constraints created via VFL absolutely are honored when the device rotates. The VFL is just a convenient syntax for creating constraints, but doesn't change what the constraints are. In my opinion, the main disadvantage with VFL syntax is that you can't (yet) represent certain types of constraints, e.g. multipliers, centerX/centerY, etc. But in contexts where the VFL is sufficient, it can be very convenient. I wouldn't dismiss it because of those problems you had in the past.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote down a few extensions that I think is going to help all developers.

```
extension UIView {

    func addView(view: UIView, top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, leading: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, trailing: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, padding: UIEdgeInsets? = .zero, width: CGFloat?, height: CGFloat?) {

        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        if !self.subviews.contains(view) {
            addSubview(view)
        }

        if let top = top {
            view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: padding?.top ?? 0).isActive = true
        }
        if let leading = left {
            view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leading, constant: padding?.left ?? 0).isActive = true
        }
        if let bottom = bottom {
            view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -(padding?.bottom ?? 0)).isActive = true
        }
        if let trailing = right {
            view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailing, constant: -(padding?.right ?? 0)).isActive = true
        }
        if let width = width, width != 0 {
            view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
        }
        if let height = height, height != 0 {
            view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
        }
    }

    func anchorSizeTo(width: NSLayoutDimension?,and height: NSLayoutDimension?) {
        if let width = width {
            self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: width).isActive = true
        }
        if let height = height {
            self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: height).isActive = true
        }
    }

    func anchorCenterTo(x: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, y: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?,with padding: CGPoint = .zero) {
        if let anchor = x {
            self.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: anchor, constant: padding.x).isActive = true
        }
        if let anchor = y {
            self.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: anchor, constant: padding.y).isActive = true
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
superView.addView(view: subView, top: upperView.bottomAnchor, leading: leftView.trailingAnchor, bottom: superView.bottom, trailing: rightView.trailingAnchor, padding: UIEdgeInsetsMake(12, 12, 12, 12), width: 0, height: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

NSLayoutAnchor class has made writing AutoLayout code much easier but still it's verbose and repetitive. You can create extension on UIView and add wrapper around AutoLayout which can be used from all UIViewControllers. For example I have added methods for size and pinning edges below

```
extension UIView {

  func size(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width),
        self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height)
    ])
  }

  func edges(_ edges: UIRectEdge, to view: UIView, offset: UIEdgeInsets) {
    if edges.contains(.top) || edges.contains(.all) {
        self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: offset.top).isActive = true
    }

    if edges.contains(.bottom) || edges.contains(.all) {
        self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: offset.bottom).isActive = true
    }

    if edges.contains(.left) || edges.contains(.all) {
        self.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: offset.left).isActive = true
    }

    if edges.contains(.right) || edges.contains(.all) {
        self.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: offset.right).isActive = true
    }
  }
}
```

now you can set constraints for the your view using just 2 lines

```
view.edges([.left, .right], to: self.view, offset: .zero)
view.size(width: 100, height: 100)
```

Comment: I like this extension could give you the right answer. Since you have really reduced the repetition. But, there are also cases where I need only one of the constraints in width and height also there is centerXAnchor and centerYAnchor.

Comment: You can create similar methods for single constraint which would solve the problem

Comment: Good extension, but we need to provide offset for all sides. For example:

`closeButton.edges([.top, .right], to: view, offset: .init(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: -8))`

Here we don't need for left and bottom, but we have to provide it. Although it's ignored, but still.

Answer (score 0):

Besides from `NSLayoutConstraint.activate` method that Rob mentioned, you can use a more general approach to eliminate multiple `.isActive = true` statements:

```
[
    view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
    view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
    view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
    view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
].forEach {$0.isActive = true}
```

The provided inline function(closure) `{$0.isActive = true}` will be called for each element of the array.

`$0` here is a shorthand parameter name. In our case it holds reference to an array element, a NSConstraint object.